# NSURL works in iPad simulator, but not on the iPad

Tags: html, ios, xcode, ipad, webview

I found some similar questions, but mine is slightly different.

I have 2 html docs loaded in the Xcode resources. One is called testpage.html, and the other is index.html. And I have a uiwebview.

testpage.html is a very bare page with just a few headers. This one works fine when I simulate the app on the iPad.

index.html is complex, with a bunch of js files (that aren't loaded into resources yet). If I try to run this page, it gives me the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'. This error occurs whether I run the app on the iPad OR the simulator.

The code I'm using to give the NSUrl is just:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testpage" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
```

I just change "testpage" to "index", and then I get this error.

THEN, I tried just copying all the code in index.html, and then pasting it into testpage.html (replacing all the code), and running that, with the url set to testpage.html. It gave me the same error. This is illuminating because it shows that it isn't something wrong with the resources.. in other words, it's not that index.html doesn't actually exist in the resources or something, because testpage.html DEFINITELY is in there and it just depends on what code is inside the actual document.

THEN, I put testpage.html back to how it was before, and ran it again, and it STILL gave me the same error!

Unless I run it in the iPad simulator, in which case it works fine.

It seems that the iPad is keeping the code for testpage.html or something, and SOMETIMES when I delete my app from the iPad, it deletes the code, and run it again, then it will successfully run with testpage.html... however this does not work every time, for some reason.

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error, and why it isn't working on the iPad? One possibility - would having hrefs to js documents that I have not loaded into resources, or having custom fonts that I have not fully set up yet, stop the code from running? It seems like it wouldn't give me this weird 'nil string parameter' error, though...

Comment: Be careful with adding certain files (such as JS), as Xcode will add them to the **Compile Sources** stage of the **Build Phases**, and not the Copy **Bundle Resources** stage.

Comment: can you try to bundle up the html, js into zip and move(unzip) to application support folder and try to load from there?